# Cocoa Touch Framework vs Cocoa Touch Static library

Tags: xcode, xcode6

Any comment on Cocoa Touch Framework vs Cocoa Touch Static library?

Can you distribute a Framework like a static library without source code?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Cocoa Touch framework support was added in Xcode 6 primarily to support [App Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html) in iOS 8 and Mac OS 10.10.  App extensions have to be built as Cocoa Touch frameworks.

Frameworks also require less manual work to set up in a project than static libraries, although [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) largely takes care of these pain points.

Frameworks can be - and are by by default - built without the source code in the build target.  Usually only header file(s) are in the target.  Therefore, you could create and share a binary only Framework.

Comment: and what (dis-)advantage has `Cocoa Touch Static Library`? framework is like dynamic library in C#, so loaded only once if more apps need it to use and call, static is loaded as many times as each app calls it?

Comment: A Cocoa Touch Static library cannot contain Swift code. If you are developing a Swift library, you must use a framework.

Comment: From a practical perspective, frameworks are only supported from iOS 8 onwards, whereas static libraries go “all the way back” to iOS 6, which is as far back as you can build an Xcode project using Xcode 7. If you need to support iOS versions before iOS 8, you should consider using a Cocoa Touch Static Library and writing your code in Objective-C.